How to change a specific page's margin without load package `geometry`?
I'm writing a manual for one of my class via l3doc class. I want to design a cover for it, but the default geometry of l3doc is that left margin is wider than the right one. So, I have to load package geometry to use its function \newgeometry and \restoregeometry.
But the geometry on the other pages changed after loading package geometry, because package geometry submerged the default geometry configuration of class l3doc. I want to keep the geometry on the other pages unchanged.
Additionally, I have tried using
\setlength {\oddsidemargin} {.9in}
\setlength {\evensidemargin} {.1in}

No matter how I adjust it, the geometry of the other pages could not restore to the default configuration of class l3doc, sob!
So, is there an alternatively way to change a specific page's margin without load package geometry?
The following is my MWE:
\documentclass{l3doc}

\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength {\oddsidemargin} {.9in}
\setlength {\evensidemargin} {.1in}

\renewcommand \maketitle
  {
    \titlepage
    \newgeometry{margin = 1in}
    ...
    \restoregeometry
    \endtitlepage
  }

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{function}{\skyrmion}
  ...
\end{function}

\end{document}

My goal is just change the margin of the title page to 1in, and other pages remain the default geometry configuration of class l3doc.

you don't need to change the geometry at all, just put the title page in a begin{minipage}{\textwidth} and then position that minipage wherever you want with \hspace({...}`

@DavidCarlisle That's an alternative method. But I'd like to know the value of \hspace{...} that can center the titlepage accurately.

the easiest way is probably to create the titlepage as a separate file and just include the pdf. however, you could load geometry with pass,verbose to get the default layout dimensions and then feed a suitably edited version back into geometry.

@cfr Perfect Solved! Thank you~

the offset you want is presumably -\oddsidemargin  if you want 1in margin, which is the result of \oddsidemargin=0pt

You can use a tikzpicture [remember picture,overlay]  and position it relative to (current page), or use \AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(x,y) {...}} and position (x,y) relative to the upper left corner.

"So, is there an alternatively way to change a specific page's margin without load package geometry?" Yes. Use \margins macro in OpTeX.
